# Classification of LED type

Tags: led, optics

Out of curiosity, I recently opened a damaged measurement device (it´s some kind of lab spectrometer, but I am not sure) that contains a LED with a package like I have not seen before (see picture).

[image]

I tried to find out what type it is since it somehow looks "special". Unfortunately, I did not find LEDs looking similar when searching through various distributor websites and I am not sure how I could narrow the search parameters.
I only know that it emitts yellow light. Does anyone have an idea which type it could be?

Comment: Looks like a normal SMD (surface-mount device) to me. They're actually quite common.

Comment: Plain old 0603 or 0805 LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a rather normal SMD LED with a clear lens. The conductor layout is quite typical.

Since the photo has no size reference, I can't be too specific, but looking for (yellow,orange,amber) SMD LEDs that have (clear,undiffused,rectangular) lens yielded this 832 matches strong list at Mouser, many of which look very similar to your photo:

https://www.mouser.de/Optoelectronics/LED-Emitters/Standard-LEDs-SMD/_/N-ec21j?P=1z0yt0uZ1z0ystyZ1z0yt3tZ1z0yrm8Z1yzu6qqZ1yzu6qsZ1yzt27lZ1yzrvh4Z1z0yqpiZ1y9c4lvZ1z0yt2qZ1z0yrdjZ1z0yt3jZ1yzu7g1Z1z0yt3s

for example, the Würth 156120YS75000

[image: Würth SMD LED]

Comment: Ah, great thanks.. "water clear" attribute for the lens was what i was missing..